# How do I increase the max PermGen size for Java from my VPS Terminal?

Tags: java, minecraft, permgen

I am trying to run a Minecraft server from a VPS hosted somewhere I don't have physical access to. I have tried searching for answers for hours on end and haven't found one that explains things in a way I can understand. All I have is remote terminal access and I need to increase my permgen size so that I can launch the FTB Crackpack server I am trying to run from it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-XX:PermSize=size` and `-XX:MaxPermSize=size` where size is the size of the permgen you want to use, `512m` (512 megabytes) is probably sufficient.

Comment: Looking more closely at the error message I noticed the problem was actually that the PermSize function had been removed from the Java I had installed. I downgraded from Java 9 to Java 8 and now it runs perfectly. Java 9 Replaces PermSize with MetaspaceSize.